# Describing $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[x])$

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In Hartshorne II.2.11, I am tasked with describing $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[x])$. Now since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, the corresponding polynomial ring is a UFD so the prime elements are exactly those that are irreducible. Since it is also an integral domain, I get that $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[x])=(0)\cup\bigcup_i(f_i)$ where $f_i$ is irreducible and monic. My question is simple. Is there a nice algebraic way to describe $\bigcup_i (f_i)$?

I know that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\bigcup_{i\geq 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^i}$, and that the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ is $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Is there a way to describe $\bigcup_i (f_i)$ as some sort of limit for instance?

Comment: a monic polynomial is given by its roots, and over a finite field, all the finite extensions are Galois with Galios group generated by Frobenius. combine these facts to understand the spec as a quotient of $\bar{F_p}$.

Comment: There are not-really-canonical bijections between the irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and the primitive necklaces made of beads of $q$ colors. (See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/769/exhibit-an-explicit-bijection-between-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-fields/1800#1800 .) This is not algebraic (I don't think there is anything more algebraic than "irreducible polynomials"), but if you are looking for a nice picture, this might be of some help.

Comment: @ali Fair enough, but I don't really understand galois theory so I'd prefer an actual statement if possible. Does it look like something we know or just a quotient?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Very interesting, I had never seen this before!

Comment: The closed points are in bijective correspondence between the elements of the set $k/\sim$, where $k=\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is an algebraic closure, and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation equating all Galois conjugates. In other words, $a\sim b$ if and only if $b=a^{p^m}$ for some integer $m$. Compare this with another exercise from Hartshorne, where he wants the students to compare $\Bbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Spec} (\Bbb{R}[x])$.

Comment: Sorry about duplicating @ali's comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No thank you actually, this is much clearer for someone that hasn't seen Galois theory!